# Create table with left anf top headings form JSON data

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, json, foreach

I have a JSON of which i need to extract headings and data inot a html table that contains top and left headings. I have provided a snippet of what the table data shoukld present. Can anyone please help with the logic of breaking down the foreach to be able to display the html corrcetly.

```
$json ='{
    "jform": {
    "product": ["3", "4"],
    "type": "101"
    },
    "mainheading": "TYPICAL ANALYSIS",
    "heading1": "NatraMin Original",
    "heading2": "NatraMin Cal-S",
    "heading3": "NatraMin Cal-K",
    "heading4": "",
    "heading5": "",
    "heading6": "",
    "heading7": "",
    "heading8": "",
    "maindata": ["Calcium", "Phosphorus"],
    "data1": ["c12%", "p12%"],
    "data2": ["c13%", "p13%"],
    "data3": ["c14%", "p14%"],
    "data4": ["", ""],
    "data5": ["", ""],
    "data6": ["", ""],
    "data7": ["", ""],
    "data8": ["", ""],
    "itemid": "2"
}';

$tableData = json_decode($json);

foreach ($tableData as $key => $value) {


    echo $key.':'.$value.'<br/>';   

}
```

The snippet below is merely the html im using to create teh sample table screengrab below it. I need to somehow incoprprate sections of that html into teh foreach. I tried nesting teh foreach but just messed it up more hence why i have removed my trys and just provided code as cleanly as possible.

```
 echo '        
    <style> 

    table {} 
    table td.top { padding: 10px; background-color: red;color: white}
    table th.top { padding: 10px; background-color: blue; color: white}
    table th.side { padding: 10px; background-color: green; color: white}
    table td { padding: 10px;  border-bottom:1px solid #ededed; text-align:center;}

    </style>

    <table class="table">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
              <th class="top" >TYPICAL ANALYSIS</th>
                <td  class="top" >NatraMin Original</td>
                <td  class="top" >NatraMin Cal-S</td>
                <td  class="top" >NatraMin Cal-K</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <th class="side" >Calcium</th>
                <td>c12%</td>
                <td>c13%</td>
                <td>c14%</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <th class="side" >Phosphorus</th>
                <td>p12%</td>
                <td>p13%</td>
                <td>p14%</td>
            </tr>

        </tbody>
    </table>';
```

[image]

When i run the very top code snippet on phptester.net i get the following output, im not too worried about the empty values i just need to make sure the values that contain data are matched up against the table properly.

```
Error Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string on line number 33
jform:
mainheading:TYPICAL ANALYSIS
heading1:NatraMin Original
heading2:NatraMin Cal-S
heading3:NatraMin Cal-K
heading4:
heading5:
heading6:
heading7:
heading8:
maindata:Array
data1:Array
data2:Array
data3:Array
data4:Array
data5:Array
data6:Array
data7:Array
data8:Array
itemid:2
```

Thanks in advance :)
John

Comment: thats because jform decodes to an object, not a string. you can check that and skip it if you want by using `if_object($value)`

Comment: I suggest you convert the `JSON` to arrays rather that objects by using `true` as the second parameter. i.e: _`$tableData = json_decode($json, true);`_

Comment: @RyanVincent thankyou, that did fix the error. I still need to know how i can display the html table within my foreach. Can you help please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what you looking for:

```
$tableData = json_decode($json, true);
$mainheading = $tableData['mainheading'];
$HTML_table = "<table>";
// headers
$HTML_table .= "<tr>";
$HTML_table .= "<th class='top1'>$mainheading</th>";
for($i=1; $i<=8; $i++) {
    $d = $tableData["heading$i"];
    if(!empty($d))
        $HTML_table .= "<th class='top2'>$d</th>";
}
$HTML_table .= "</tr>";
// end of headings

// main data
$mainData = $tableData['maindata'];
$mainDataCount = count($mainData);
for($i=0; $i<$mainDataCount; $i++) {
    $d = $mainData[$i];
    $HTML_table .= "<tr>";
    $HTML_table .= "<td class='side'>$d</td>";
    for($j=1; $j<=8; $j++) {
        $d = $tableData["data$j"][$i];
        if(!empty($d))
            $HTML_table .= "<td>$d</td>";
    }
    $HTML_table .= "</tr>";
}
$HTML_table .= "</table>";
?>
```

In HTML, the `<th>` is conceptually used for header cells, not the starting cell of a row, so I've also changed them in the code and of course in the `<style>`:

```
<style>
    table {} 
    table th.top1 { padding: 10px; background-color: red;color: white}
    table th.top2 { padding: 10px; background-color: blue; color: white}
    table td.side { padding: 10px; background-color: green; color: white}
    table td { padding: 10px;  border-bottom:1px solid #ededed; text-align:center;}
</style>
```

To get the result printed, simple do `echo $HTML_table;` anywhere you want to :)